# What would cause timeouts on a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout

I am getting the following error ONLY for queries run on the ReportingPeriod table (see below).  This happens even when I comment-out the related LEFT JOIN on another table.  There aren't more than 200 records in the table.  Additionally, it doesn't matter if I run the query outright or run it using the stored procedure.  Lastly, other tables & procedures run fine.

Any idea what may cause this?

**VERSION**
Sql-Server 2005

**ERROR:**
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

**RAW QUERY:**

```
DECLARE @ProjectsKey INT
SET @ProjectsKey = 1234
-----------------------------
    SELECT 
        ReportingPeriodKey
        ,ReportingPeriod.ProjectsKey
        --,Phase.PhaseKey AS PhaseKey
        --,Phase.Name AS PhaseName
        ,[Type]
        ,ReportingPeriodStart
        ,ReportingPeriodEnd
    FROM   
        ReportingPeriod
--  LEFT JOIN
--  (
--      SELECT
--          PhaseKey
--          ,ProjectsKey
--          ,Name
--      FROM dbo.Phase
--  ) AS Phase ON Phase.PhaseKey = dbo.ReportingPeriod.PhaseKey
    WHERE
        ((@ProjectsKey IS NOT NULL AND ReportingPeriod.ProjectsKey = @ProjectsKey) OR @ProjectsKey IS NULL)
    ORDER BY
        ReportingPeriodStart
```

**TABLE DEFINITION:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReportingPeriod](
    [ReportingPeriodKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [ProjectsKey] [int] NOT NULL,   
    [PhaseKey] [int] NOT NULL, [Type] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,     
    [ReportingPeriodStart] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportPeriod_Start]  DEFAULT (getdate()),     
    [ReportingPeriodEnd] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportPeriod_End]  DEFAULT(getdate()),  
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ReportingPeriod_CreatedDate] DEFAULT (getdate()),  
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL,  
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ReportPeriod] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ( [ReportingPeriodKey] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReportingPeriod] WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ReportingPeriod_attrReportingPeriodType]
FOREIGN KEY([Type]) REFERENCES [dbo].[attrReportingPeriodType] ([FullName]) 

GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReportingPeriod]  
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ReportingPeriod_attrReportingPeriodType]

GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReportingPeriod] WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ReportingPeriod_Phase] 
FOREIGN KEY([PhaseKey]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Phase] ([PhaseKey]) 

GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReportingPeriod] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ReportingPeriod_Phase]

GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReportingPeriod] WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ReportingPeriod_Projects] 
FOREIGN KEY([ProjectsKey]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectsKey]) 

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReportingPeriod]
CHECK CONSTRAINT
[FK_ReportingPeriod_Projects]
```

**SYSTEM STATS**
There are 2 sets for object_id #875866187

reserved_page_count = 17
used_page_count = 11
row_count = 306

reserved_page_count = 2
used_page_count = 2
row_count = 306

Comment: You should not use both quote and code tags.

Comment: @Emre Could you please elaborate on this comment...thanks.

Comment: You use both `<blockquote>` and `<code>` tag in your table definition which make your code less readable. Please remove qutation symbols (whihc is `>`) from your code in order to make it more readable.

Comment: Please specify and/or tag the specific or minimum version of SQL Server you are using, since our ability to investigate session/spid activity has changed through different versions.

Comment: Further questions - do ReportingPeriodStart/End really get set to getdate(), with milliseconds and everything? Also, are there any indexes on this table? You say there are only 200 rows but what is showing in sys.dm_db_partition_stats for this table (WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ReportingPeriod')? Finally, your WHERE clause only needs the comparison, not the check if the parameter is NOT NULL. Equality to NULL will return false anyway.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, we need the milliseconds. Which stats are you most interested in?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the point of setting start and end both to GETDATE()? Reporting periods usually reflect actual periods, such as a full day, week, month, etc. - not sure why milliseconds would be important here. Anyway the stats I am interested in are reserved_page_count, used_page_count, row_count for that object_id.

Comment: The database is bi-temporal...so the time stamps become important quickly.  I will update the above momentarily.  Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried checking for open transactions that may be locking the table?

```
dbcc opentran

exec sp_who 69
-- Where the id is the SPID from DBCC OPENTRAN

exec sp_lock 69
-- Where the id is the SPID from DBCC OPENTRAN

select * from sys.objects where object_id = 2089058478
-- Where the id is the ObjID from sp_lock
```

Comment: I am a fan of `sp_who2` for identifying blocking SPIDs. The `BlkBy` field tells you the blocking SPID and you can then use `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<blocking_spid>)` to identify what query is causing the blocking to happen.

Comment: I added exec to the two stored procedure calls. As a batch it will fail without them.

Comment: as a batch, you won't know the spids, etc :)

Answer (score 1):

> Check if the query is being blocked, note the sessionID (seen at the bottom of query window) of the SQL statement or proc and then fire below query, check if BlkBy column is not empty for your sessionID

```
EXEC SP_WHO2
```

Also execute your query in one window and then in another window execute below query to see if any other processes are running that are having a lock on the table

```
 select text, session_id,
start_time, status, db_name(database_id) as DBName, blocking_session_id,
wait_type, wait_resource
from sys.dm_Exec_requests der
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text (der.sql_handle)
```

Also test and change the transaction isolation level allowing dirty reads as a final option as below:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Now you can also check for any currently running transactions using this DMV and look for request_mode column for any Xclusive locks on the table concerned.

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS
```

Answer (score 0):

Something most likely has a lock on one of the tables in your select. You can test whether your proc is being blocked by running the below query while you proc is executing

```
select spid, blocked, login_time, nt_username, hostname, program_name 
from sys.sysprocesses
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For 2005+ much better in general to use the DMVs (sys.dm_exec_sessions|requests) than the compatibility views like sysprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are worried about dirty reads from the table tReportingPeriod you could just use:

```
FROM ReportingPeriod WITH (NOLOCK)
```

in your query.

Comment: First, it would be best to understand why the table is locked in the first place. If it's some kind of back-end object talking to the database, maybe they haven't disposed of it and a transaction is still open.

Comment: Sure I agree, but once that problem is fixed you may still want to use NOLOCK anyway if you are happy with dirty reads